# Is there a way to reuse tiles on subsequent zoom levels with a Mapbox-gl-js map?

Tags: reactjs, raster, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I am trying to reuse tiles across subsequent zoom levels so my map doesn't need to fetch tiles at odd zoom levels. I have come across the documentation below explaining how to do this in openlayers but I have not been able to replicate this behavior on Mapbox.

I attempted to intercept requests for tiles using the transformRequest function on the map object but have not been successful in throwing away the unnecessary requests that come from the odd zoom levels. Does anybody have any suggestions on how I would go about implementing this?

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles-advanced.html